# jest ignore all node_modules except 1 package

Tags: testing, jestjs, babeljs

I'm using jest for doing testing and currently I can ignore node_modules. The issue, however, is that theres 1 package in node_modules that I want to get transpiled with babel. Right now my ignored patterns look like this:

```
testPathIgnorePatterns: ['./node_modules/'],
```

if my package is called 'my-package', how can I make it so testPathIgnorePatterns doesn't ignore that inside node_modules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR - use this config key with this regex:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules\/(?!my-package)(.*)']
```

---

This is a 2 part answer.

**Part 1 - the regex**

The `testPathIgnorePatterns` key takes an array of strings/regex, so I can pass a regex that will match all node_modules except the one I want with something like this:

```
// one way to do it
testpathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules\/(?!my-package).+\.js$']

// another way to do it - this regex seems simpler to me
testpathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules\/(?!my-package)(.*)']
```

this basically says, ignore all node_modules except my-package. However, the thing to note here is, `testPathIgnorePatterns` does not determine whether a module should be transpiled by babel or not. This key is for jest to know where your test files are. Basically, using this key, you're telling jest 'dont look in `node_modules` for files with the `.test.js` extension', because you don't want to run the tests of imported node_module packages.

So, in reality, you want to ignore this setting completely because jest will automatically default it to `['/node_modules/']`, or if you wanted to add other paths to ignore, you'd need:

```
testpathIgnorePatterns: ['other/file/path', '/node_modules/']
```

**Part 2 - where to use the regex**

Given the context from part 1, the correct place to put the regex to allow jest to transpile specific packages from node_modules is: `transformIgnorePatterns`. So it would look like this:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules\/(?!my-package)(.*)']
```

this way, jest will not transpile any node_modules packages except 'my-package'. I believe the default value for both of the keys mentioned above is 'node_modules' - meaning, node_modules is automatically ignored in both the `testPath` and the `transform`

[Jest docs for these configuration settings](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-object-string-string)

Comment: you've saved me hours!