# Running Jest test get error "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

In my node.js (with typescript) project, I try to use [crypto-random-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-random-string) package for generating random string value.

I use [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) installed it:

```
pnpm i crypto-random-string
```

In my production code I use it as:

```
import cryptoRandomString from 'crypto-random-string';

const cryptoStr = () => cryptoRandomString({ length: 10, type: 'ascii-printable' });
```

I have a jest code to unit test it, but when run jest, it complains:

```
my-project/node_modules/.pnpm/crypto-random-string@5.0.0/node_modules/crypto-random-string/index.js:3
    import {promisify} from 'node:util';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import cryptoRandomString from 'crypto-random-string';
```

My `jest.config.ts`:

```
export default {
  jest: {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    transform: {
      'node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!variables/.*)'],
  },
};
```

I tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781271/jest-wont-transform-the-module-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outsi), but not helpful for me.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Does accessing files outside of jest work fine?

Comment: And are you using babel? I think you must have babel to transform ts and jsx to jest-readable

Comment: I need to know more

Comment: I had the similar issue but the provided answer does not work for me

Comment: Have you reviewed the info message when this fails?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101834/10625420) worked for me in my `jest.config.js`. Specifically:

```js
module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules\/(?!crypto-random-string)(.*)']
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use babel.
In server package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11"    
  "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
  "jest": "^27.5.1",
  },

  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

And client package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-babel": "^1.0.1",
    "parcel": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

If that does not work, could you also provide the test file?

Comment: Having exact the same package.json and babel.config.cjs with values under "babel" key I'm still getting `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error. Also tried `ts-jest` and `transformIgnorePatterns`, nothing works